# Merge sort not working

Tags: c, sorting

I have been working on merge sort and I have written some code for it but it is not working as per the given algorithm. I exactly did according to the algorithm but seems like something is wrong. Please anyone let me know whats wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[] = {5, 3, 2, 4, 9, 1, 11, 6, 10};
    mergeSort(a, 0, sizeof(a)/ sizeof(int));
    printArray(a);
}

void mergeSort(int a[], int low, int high){
    int med;
    if(high - low > 1){
        med = (high - low) / 2 + low;
        mergeSort(a, low, med);
        mergeSort(a, med+1, high);
        merge(a, low, med, high);
    }
}
void printArray(int a[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void merge(int a[], int low, int med, int high){
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = low;
    int a1[9];
    int a2[9];
    for(i = 0; i < med; i++){
        a1[i] = a[i];
    }

    for(i = med; i < high; i++){
        a2[i] = a[i];
    }

    while(i < high - med && j < med - low){
        if(a1[i] <= a2[j]){
            a[k] = a1[i];
            i++;
        }else{
            a[k] = a2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }

    while(i < high - med){
        a[k] = a1[i];
        i++;
    }

    while(j < med - low){
        a[k] = a2[j];
        j++;
    }

}
```

Algorithm : https://i.stack.imgur.com/f73Zi.jpg

Comment: As a first point, your functions are in the wrong order: Try to always put a function above all its callers, otherwise you need forward-declarations. I guess you just disregarded the compiler-warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got that algorithm from but the end of it (the 2 last while loops) is incorrect. You also copied parts of it down wrong. I'll leave out stuff that didn't change and is unnecessary.

All of my comments indicate where code changed.

```
void mergeSort(int a[], int low, int high){
    int med;
    if(high - low > 1){
        med = (high - low) / 2 + low;
        mergeSort(a, low, med);
        mergeSort(a, med, high); //you copied this down wrong. med NOT med + 1
        merge(a, low, med, high);
    }
}
void merge(int a[], int low, int med, int high){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = low;
    int a1[9];
    int a2[9];
    for(i = 0; i < med; i++){
        //algorithm states to copy by doing: a1[0 -> med] = a[low -> med - 1]
        //we're copying the subarray 'a' from 'low' to 'med - 1' into
        //'a1' from 0 to 'med'
        a1[i] = a[i + low];
    }

    for(i = med; i < high; i++){
        //algorithm states to copy by doing: a2[0 -> med] = a[med -> high - 1]
        a2[i - med] = a[i];
    }

    //don't forget to reset i to 0
    i = 0;

    while(i < med - low && j < high - med){
        if(a1[i] <= a2[j]){
            a[k] = a1[i];
            i++;
        }else{
            a[k] = a2[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while(i < med - low){
        a[k] = a1[i];
        i++;
        k++;
        //algorithm didn't have k++ for some reason
    }

    while(j < high - med){
        //note it's a2[j] not a2[i]
        //algorithm was wrong here
        a[k] = a2[j];
        j++;
        k++;
        //didn't have k++ here either
    }
}
```

The last 3 while loops can be made shorter with post-increment operators in the array index since we know our intent is to increment them after the statement has completed (hence *post*-increment).

```
    while(i < med - low && j < high - med){
        if(a1[i] <= a2[j])
            a[k++] = a1[i++];
        else
            a[k++] = a2[j++];
    }

    while(i < med - low)
        a[k++] = a1[i++];

    while(j < high - med)
        a[k++] = a2[j++];
```

Comment: thank you so much... how could I define the array size of a1 and a2 dynamically

Comment: @xyz abc one way you could do it is by passing in the size of the array to the function and use malloc. The size will obviously change so you would need to account for that.